# Typescript error assigning class to DOM object

Tags: typescript

Creating DOM objects. Trying to understand the following.

Typescript is giving me an error on the `article.classList`; but if I use `article.setAttribute('class', 'flip service')` it works fine.

`article.classList` works fine in JS but not in TS, why do I have to use `setAttribute` ?

even more confusing for me `article.title = service.name` works in both JS and TS

error:

```
[ts] Cannot assign to 'classList' because it is a constant or a read-   only property.
(property) Element.classList: DOMTokenList
```

code

```
let article = document.createElement('article')
article.title = service.name
article.classList = 'flip service'
article.setAttribute('data-type', 'service')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of just assigning (to a read-only value), use the `DOMTokenList#add` method instead:

```
article.classList.add('flip', 'service');
```

For further reading, see [`Element.classList` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).